# html files on local Server IIS

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple .html files on my local IIS Server.

**For example:**

- Index.htm (The default page)
- page1.htm
- page2.htm
- page3.htm
- page4.htm

All the pages are connected per Hyperlinks with each other.
**Like** from Index.htm to page1.htm, and from page1.htm to page3.htm etc...

My problem is the following:
In the beginning i would start at the index.htm, because it is the default html file. And i navigate through the files due to the hyperlink.
Let's say that the last visited page was page3.htm. And then i closed everything.

What should i do to start at the next time from the last page (page3.htm) or any other page?

I searched a lot and found no solution for my problem! I would very thankful for every tip or code in javascript!

Comment: You would also save my day!

Comment: This depends on your workflow - do you want the user to start off from the last page? does the user needs to be authenticated to access this page? Or does the user need to re-authenticate. Depends on what you are trying to do?

Comment: See this doc that, could help you http://appcropolis.com/blog/howto/restore-last-visited-page-using-cookies/

Comment: Or try something short way like window.location.href = window.history.back(1);

Comment: The user should start off from the last page, he doesn't need to be authenticated to access this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**window.localStorage**

This acts in a similar way to a cookie, the setting is stored with the browser until cache is cleared or you script to delete the value.

The following script shows you how to set and retrieve the value
All you need to do is either use a switch statement to decide which page to load and use a window.location to set the path to the page you wish to diver the user to.

```js
function funPage(intPage){
  intPage = parseInt(intPage);  // this converts the string to an integer fro
  window.localStorage.setItem("page", intPage);
  var strPage;
  switch(intPage){
    case 1:
      strPage = "index";
      break;
    case 2:
      strPage = "2";
      break;
    case 3:
      strPage = "3";
      break;
    case 4:
      strPage = "4";
      break;
    case 5:
      strPage = "5";
      break;
    default:
      /*
        wont be used but its there incase you modify the code and its a back up.
        you could use switch (true) and test case (parseInt(strPageNo > 1) && parseInt(strPageNo < 6)
        and set strPage = strPageNo; but i have deliberatly coded it this way to allow you to set page
        names such as "help.html" instead of 6.html
      */
      strPage = "index";
    break;
  }
  
  window.location = strPage + ".html";
}


function funLoadPage(){
  var strPageNo = window.localStorage.getItem("page");
  if (typeof(strPageNo) == "undefined"){
    strPageNo = "1";
  }
  funPage(strPageNo);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funLoadPage, false);
```

```css
footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px ;
}
```

```html
<h1>Page header</h1>
<article>
<h2>This is my article</h2>
<p>The content of my page would go here</p>
</article>

<footer>
<nav class="pagination">
Page: 

<a onclick="funPage(1)" href="#">1</a>
<a onclick="funPage(2)" href="#">2</a>
<a onclick="funPage(3)" href="#">3</a>
<a onclick="funPage(4)" href="#">4</a>
<a onclick="funPage(5)" href="#">5</a>

</nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much!
Would you please adjust your code to my example?

Answer (score -1):

*Agree with @DataCure, and something that he forgot to mentioned.*

---

First of All -- **HTTP is stateless protocol**, so in simple words you cant achieve directly.  Now the question is then how to work with Stateless protocol when we need to pass some information from client to Server.??

Yes we have some technique  to pass some value from client to server in http stateless protocol, and the most popular is `cookies`.  Because whenever you load the page from the same browser, what is does it grab the cookies for that particular site if any available in browser local storage and then pass that cookies in the header of the request you made to the server.

And finally you can use that cookie at server to perform some action.

Now question arises how to set the cookie at client (browser's local storage) so that we can send it back to server.??  Generally we send the cookies from the server in response header from the server, and that cookie will reside at client and will be used as explained above.

But as you said you are using pure html at server side, so directly you cant send cookie from server to client.  But yes we can create cookies at client side using javascript. ([can refer W3school link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)).

But because you can creating the cookie at client, you are using **pure html at server side**, you have to send another call to server on the basis on cookie.

> document.cookie = "CurrentPageName; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/;";

and then you can get this value and redirect on page.